# Dash ploty updating figures data using a time dropdown

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm building a simple dashboard in Dash where i have two callback function one is for a checklist which decides which figures to show and the other a dropdown for selecting the time range for the data that I'm reading from a remote postgres server.
so the problem is i cant seem to find a way to connect the two callback function as one selects the range and the other uses this data range to draw figures
**
Callback 1:**

```
@app.callback(
    Output('filtered-data', 'data'),
    Input('range_selector','value'),
)

def update_range_data(selected_range,selected_values):
    global df
    global filtered_df
    curtime = df['time'].iloc[-1]
    selected_tr = curtime - timedelta(hours= selected_range)
    filtered_df = df[df['time']>= selected_tr]   
    return filtered_df.to_json(date_format='iso', orient='split')
```

**Callback 2:**

```
@app.callback(
    Output('example-graph', 'figure'),
    Input('cl' , 'value'),
    State('filtered-data', 'data'), 
)

def update_gauge(selected_values,filtered_data_json):
    if filtered_data_json is None:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
    filtered_df = pd.read_json(filtered_data_json)  
    num_gauges = len(selected_values)
    vertical_gap = 50

    fig = go.Figure()

    for i, value in enumerate(selected_values, start=1):
        domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [(i - 1) / num_gauges, i / num_gauges]}  # Adjust the positioning as needed
        
        gauge = go.Indicator(
            mode="gauge+number",
            value=df[value].iloc[0],  # You may need to adjust this value based on your data
            title={'text': value},
            gauge={'axis': {'range': [None, 100]}, 'bar': {'color': "red"}},
            domain=domain,
        )

        fig.add_trace(gauge)

    fig.update_layout(
        showlegend=False,
        height=(200 + vertical_gap) * num_gauges - vertical_gap,  # Adjust the height as needed
        paper_bgcolor="#023e8a",
        font_color="white",
    )
    return fig
```

i have tried using states to store the data as a buffer and then read from that buffer but that hasnt worked